# Extending lifetime of std::tuple<int&,int> by assigning it to const std::tuple<int, int>&

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I was using the `std::tuple` class and found something I would say is rather unexpected behavior.

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int i = 20;
std::tuple<int&, int> f() {
    return std::tuple<int&, int>(i, 0);
}

int main() {
    const std::tuple<int, int>& t = f();
    int j = ++i;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << "\n";
}
```

This seems to compile and print `20` on all major compilers. Is this standard conforming, or undefined behavior as the two types are different? I know that one can extend the lifetime of a temporary by assigning it to `const T&`, but as far as I know `std::tuple<int&, int>` is not the same type as `std::tuple<int, int>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not UB.

> but as far as I know `std::tuple<int&, int>` is not the same type as `std::tuple<int, int>`.

Yes, and reference can't bind to object with different type directly. Given `const std::tuple<int, int>& t = f();`, the returned `std::tuple<int&, int>` will be [converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) to `std::tuple<int, int>` implicitly, which is a temporary `std::tuple<int, int>`. Then the temporary is bound to `t` and gets lifetime extended to the lifetime of `t`.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, but it seems like the crowd disagrees...

Comment: @Mestkon Well, it's up to you. :)

Answer (score 8):

This is well defined behavior.

```
const std::tuple<int, int>& t = f();
```

is not giving you a reference to the tuple you created in `f()` because they have different types.  Instead what happens is a temporary `std::tuple<int, int>` is created from `f()`'s return and then that temporary is bound to `t`.  Since this is a copy you get the value of `i` at that point in time and are no longer coupled to it.

Had you used

```
const std::tuple<int&, int>& t = f();
```

then `21` would have been printed since you would still have a reference to `i` in the tuple.

Comment: Yes, 20 is the expected output, but the fact that the implicit conversion before binding to const std::tuple<int, int>& is allowed is surprising to me.

Comment: @Mestkon Well a `std::tuple<int, int>` and a `std::tuple<int&, int>` are not the same thing so a conversion has to happen.  The type the reference binds to must match the what the reference is declared to bind.

Comment: Yes I understand that a conversion is necessary, but when I tried it for the first time I expected a hard type mismatch compile error, but it can see how it makes sense to allow implicit conversion in this case now yes.